# How to import erroneous geometry records into PostGIS for fixing?

Tags: postgis, geopackage, open-source-gis

New to PostGIS.  I have a few large multipolygon datasets with errors that PostGIS should be able to fix quite efficiently.  However, when in QGIS I try to import the layers into PostGIS, it will error out and stop importing when it reaches an invalid geometry.

The data currently is spread among a series of geopackages that load fine in QGIS, but the layers contain many errors.  My desire is to use PostGIS to fix the errors.  There are too many to manually fix.

How do I get invalid geometry into PostGIS so that I can use the various `ST_` wrappers to fix it?

Comment: are they shapefiles? did you look into ogr2ogr?

Comment: See OP: they are geopackages.  I searched google for "import layers from geopackage to postgis using ogr2ogr"  and it did not turn up any CLI examples for doing this.

Comment: How are you importing the layers into PostGIS?

Comment: @DPSSpatial QGIS DB Manager. I load the GeoPackage file in QGIS,  load the DB Manager, and attempt to import the layer.

Comment: @auslander do the Topology Checker plugin tools work on geopackages?

Comment: @DPSSpatial the openstreetmap polygons I'm working with do not adhere to a topology, but even if so, the topology checker only shows me errors, it does not fix them.  My question is: PostGIS has `ST_MakeValid()` which means that it must be possible for PostGIS to hold invalid geometry or the method would make no sense.  How do I get that invalid geometry into PostGIS from a GeoPackage?

Comment: tbh I don't know what a geopackage is but if you could save it to a shapefile or geojson I would open it up in python and insert the feature row by row into a postgis table. I can post some helpful code if this is an option for you

Comment: @auslander agreed with Ziggy - unless your workflow will constantly rely on Geopackages with invalid geometry - convert to SHP first, even try to import without fixing, then if you need to try using the TopologyChecker to find errors, then fix them manually - My experience with the ST_MakeValid() doesn't necessarily fix everything - I use the ST_IsValid() function and the ST_IsValidDetail() to pinpoint my errors once loaded into PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks ziggy and @DPSSpatial - I am hesitant to cast db-stored features to shapefile in anything but edge cases because in the case that I have time data or long field names, it will truncate these data when converting to shapefile.

Comment: @auslander perhaps then importing to Spatialite rather than SHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL is an abstarction library and there is no need to have documentation for each possible import-export combination. It is usually enough to read the documentation of ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and the output driver that is in your case http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html. Your command will be about

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='databasename' host='addr' port='5432' user='x' password='y'" my_geopackage.gpkg
```

Ogr2ogr does not try to validate the geometries during conversion and you have good possibilities to get also the invalid geometries into PostGIS.

Comment: this seemed to work, but resulted in tables in postgis that would not load into qgis ("not a valid layer and can not be added to the map.")  I reviewed the GDAL driver documentation for gpkg, and do not see any examples that point me where I need to go (they all focus on converting TO geopackage, not from it). I tried doing `ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"pg connection string here" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom my_file.gpkg` and this wrote the tables to the db, but they were also rejected as invalid.

Comment: Nevermind - it turns out I was trying to drag the layer from the QGIS DB Manager into QGIS, and it was failing (probably a separate bug).  When I loaded the layer directly from PostGIS, it worked.  Thanks!